# Random saving of audio/picture of a video in the gallery

Tags: video, photo

I watch a lot of videos,movies,etc.I have observed that sometimes when i transfer video files from hard-drive/USB to 'Videos' in my system a random snapshot of the video is taken as the cover pic of a an audio file and it is automatically stored in the gallery.Wheni i play it,only the audio plays,the background is blank.
Also sometimes it seems Ubuntu has a mind of its own.when i try to delete these snapshots from the gallery,it does not respond and simply closes the gallery.Also the videos stored in 'videos' are sometimes deleted without my knowledge.What is going on?I would like for this to stop.There is only 1 user,and the videos are generally opened with VLc or the default video player.

Comment: how many users are on your system? Malicious users and code do exist in linux. Are these videos playing streaming via your browser, or in flash? or are they saved some place? what are you viewing the videos with? gstreamer will play the first 10 seconds of audio from a media file, as a preview, are you perhaps looking at preview files? turn on your firewall using the command `sudo ufw enable` if you have ssh or some other remote sessions enabled, you might disable those while you figure out whats happening.